# Solving a coupled second order differential equation, for a particles path.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, physics

I was tasked with finding the path a particle takes through this potential function.

$$U(x)=x^2+xy+y^2$$

I then took the gradient, and this produced a pair of differential equations.

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{m}(-2x-y)$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{m}(-2y-x)$$

I have yet to encounter a problem of this form. It looks simple, but it has proven to be very tricky to solve. I tried a couple substitution techniques that initially seemed promising but inevitably failed. I even used Laplace transforms, but that got very messy and I eventually gave up.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Set $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}&=-\frac{3u}m\\
\frac{d^2v}{dt^2}&=-\frac{v}m
\end{align}
are easily solved scalar equation. In general you have to decouple the system $m\ddot q=-Aq$ via the eigen-decomposition of the system matrix $A$.

Comment: How did we go from $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$ to the scalar equation? Do you have a link I could get to read up on this method? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Just add and subtract the equations. In other words, the eigenvectors of $\pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}$ are $(1,1)^T$ and $(1,-1)^T$.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much!